# How to make tableview refresh from same row in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have 3 tableview which have 10 rows, after pull to scroll it adds next 10 rows, but the scroll goes to top, I want it from the same row, which was before.

```
- (void)insertRowAtBottom {
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self moreClicked];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last index path of the table view in any variable when pull happens and then use the below code to scroll the table

```
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(numberOfRows - 1) inSection:(numberOfSections - 1)];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastIndexPath inSection:0];
[self.tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                         animated:YES];
```

For Scroll positions you can have any value within the list.

```
UITableViewScrollPositionNone,
UITableViewScrollPositionTop,
UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle,
UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to implement "paging" in tableView.

One approach is: Assuming your tableView is populated from an objects array - 
When you scroll down and fetch the next 10 items - just append the newly added data to your datasource array, and then call `[self.tableview reloadData];`

this will keep you exactly where you were. no need for scrolling methods or animations.